# Subdomain vhost.conf on Plesk 11

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost

I'm using Plesk 11.0.9 - centOS and I'd like to change the vhost.conf file for a subdomain, but the path I'm using seem to be wrong :

```
/var/www/vhosts/sub.domain.lu/conf/vhost.conf
```

Is it the right path ?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the correct path. The content you put there will be included into autogenerated config file of Plesk. If you need to change config rather than to add/override anything there, you'll have to change templates used for config generation. More information can be found in [Virtual Host Configuration](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/68625.htm) chapter of Plesk docs

Answer (score 1):

You should use command like:

## /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain sub.domain.lu

to apply your custom web server Apache configuration file changes.
On previous versions of Plesk the same job has been done by command:

## /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --vhost-name=sub.domain.lu